# Find rows that hasn't a defined relation with a selected row in other table?

Tags: mysql, join

I have two table like following ones:

```
users
-----
id | name
_________
 1 | mert
 2 | ersin
 3 | faruk

friends
-------
id | follower | following
_________________________
1  |    2     |    3     |
2  |    3     |    1     |
__________________________
```

I want to find people who don't follow the selected person.

For example:

```
get_people_not_follow(2) // "ersin"
Result: array(array(1, 'mert'), array(3, 'faruk'));

get_people_not_follow(1) // "mert"
Result: array(array(2, 'ersin'));
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "select * from friends INNER JOIN users ON users.id=friends.follower where friends.following!=$id GROUP BY users.id" When I use that, it doesn't return any user that doesn't exist in friends table. Its order must be reversed. But i couldn't do that. Sorry for my English. I couldn't tell clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT users.id, name
FROM users LEFT JOIN friends ON (following = users.id AND follower = ##)
WHERE friends.id IS NULL
```

Where `##` is the ID you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks. :) It returns people who don't be followed by ##. I want to get people who don't follow ##.

Comment: Could be I got `follower` and `following` backward. Just swap them.